# Is this a way to check whether or not a LinkedList node is initialized?

Tags: c++, if-statement, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create an insert-at-end function for a linked list class. I was having some trouble, so I looked up some code and found the following:

```
if (!start) // empty list becomes the new node
{
    start = newNode;
    return;
}
```

This seems to be a check to make sure that if the user uses the function with an empty list, the newly created "ending" node, `newNode`, becomes the start node. But, what does `if (!start)` do? (`start` is the head node).

Comment: Impossible to tell from the code fragment. With insert at end, it is far better to use both a `head` and `tail` pointer to retain O(1) insertions at the end of the list. e.g. [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) which you can extend to a template implementation as [C++ Template Singly-Linked List w/Sort](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15) (good for ~ 100,000 nodes due to limit of recursive merge-sort)

Comment: *"start is the head node"* -- this warrants a double check. Is `start` the head node, or is it a *pointer* to the head node? That makes a significant difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!start) // empty list becomes the new node
{
    start = newNode;
    return;
}
```

`!` negates whats in `start`. So if start is `NULL` then `!NULL` meaning true so it goes inside and make it as a start node. Similarly when start is  not `NULL` then it doesn't go inside.

Comment: That's what's happening, but why did the programmer do this? What makes this behaviour desirable? And ultimately you still need to answer the question: is this a check for an initialized node?

Comment: I believe the actual question is what is the meaning of `!start` so I answered that. You are right, we can provide better alternatives and suggestions if programmer provided more info.

Answer (score 2):

A linked list is implemented as a chain of **pointers** to node objects.

Empty

```
---------
| start | -> nullptr
---------
```

1 node

```
---------    ---------
| start | -> | value |
---------    ---------
             | next  | -> nullptr
             ---------
```

2 nodes

```
---------    ---------      ---------
| start | -> | value |  |-> | value |
---------    ---------  |   ---------
             | next  | -|   | next  | -> nullptr
             ---------      ---------
```

And so on...

The expression `if (!start)` is checking whether the `start` **pointer** is null, which it should be if the list is empty. The expression is equivalent to `if (start == nullptr)` when checking a **pointer**.

Assuming a single-linked list, then chances are that your function is likely implemented roughly similar to the following:

```cpp
void insertAtEnd(T value)
{
    node *newNode = new node;
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if (!start) // if (start == nullptr)
    {
        start = newNode;
        return;
    }

    node *n = start;
    while (n->next) // while (n->next != nullptr)
    {
        n = n->next;
    }

    n->next = newNode;
}
```

A simpler and preferred way to implement this function would look more like the following:

```cpp
void insertAtEnd(T value)
{
    node **n = &start;
    while (*n) // while (*n != nullptr) 
    {
        n = &((*n)->next);
    }

    *n = new node;
    (*n)->value = value;
    (*n)->next = nullptr;
}
```